# Why doesn't polarity matter for fuel injectors?

Tags: electrical, fuel-injectors, theory

Why doesn't polarity matter for fuel injectors? If they are essentially a solenoid, then it seems it would matter; swapping polarity would change the direction the electromagnet pulls or pushes.

Comment: In the case of a solenoid that's picky about polarity, there are likely two magnets that pull in opposite directions. I believe that injectors use a magnet and a spring, but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

Like normal magnets, electro magnets can only attract (pull) metallic objects, so the injector coil could not repel the solenoid valve.